# Resize centering force / change center - d3js v4

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to do that : [Resizable Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3355967)

But using d3v4 !

I think, I have to convert this line, from v3 to v4

```
force.size([width, height]).resume();
```

In the v4 doc, I found this : [v4 Doc about centering force / center.x & center.y](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#center_x)

I tried many things ! But without success.

Thanks in advance :)

(And many thanks to **mbostock** for creating d3js :D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understood the doc !

```
var simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2))
```

To change the center

```
simulation.force("center")
    .x(window.innerWidth / 2)
    .y(window.innerHeight / 2);

simulation.alpha(0.3).restart();
```

Comment: I am trying to use this but it is not really working for me. However, I can see how the code changes the position of the force graph, but I don't see I it would resize it (shrink or expand) depending on the changing window.

Comment: @Fede9390 If you want to resize a SVG element according to your window size :
`window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
 svg.attr("width", window.innerWidth).attr("height", window.innerHeight);
});`